# How to apply different style for nested child list

Tags: css

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Qrbm4/1/). How can I apply different style to my nested list (>Nested 1. and >Nested 2) rather than its parent list?

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geneva</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Nested 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nested 2</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a href="#">Winterthur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lausanne</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lucerne</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add id or classes for your nested lists and than apply your styles http://jsfiddle.net/Qrbm4/3/

Comment: You could use a class on the list you want to style, and in your css, use the appropriate selector to apply the style to those list items. `<ul class="styledList">` then in the css, select the list items with `.styledList li`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `li li a` to select those elements. For example:

```
li li a {
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Qrbm4/2/)**

Comment: Does this work because it just checks to see if there is the previous element somewhere up its hierarchy? At first glance I didn't think it would work, because the `li` that have the `a` element are within an `ul`, not a `li`, but I guess it applies to any `a` that has an ancestor `li` that has an ancestor `li`, anywhere in their hierarchy?

Comment: @Zack - _"Does this work"_ Well yeah, you can see by the fiddle it works. You may be confusing `li li` with the child selector `li > li` (which wouldn't work anyway).

Comment: I saw that it *did* work, and was asking *why* it worked. You're right, I probably got [Descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) and [Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) mixed up.

Comment: `li li a` will select anchors that are descendants of at least two list items. It doesn't specify proximity.

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this through classes added to the `<ul>` elements, then use the appropriate css selector to apply the style.

Add the class to the `<ul>` tag you want to style.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geneva</a>
       <ul class="styledList">
         <li><a href="#">Nested 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nested 2</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a href="#">Winterthur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lausanne</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lucerne</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in the css sheet, apply styling to that class name, or just to the `<li>` elements within that list, whatever is appropriate.

## Apply to `<ul>` and all decendants

```
.styledList {
  // css style
}
```

## Apply only to `<li>` inside the `<ul>`

```
.styledList li {
  // css style
}
```

The `.` in the selector is used to specify that the style is applied to the elements with that class, or you can use the `#` selector to specify an ID that you want the style applied to, such as

```
<div id="styledDiv">Hello</div>
```

css

```
#styledDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you want to learn more about CSS selectors, you can check out the W3 article
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html
and here is the class selectors in particular
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html